# How to add Flutter analyze for linting as a build step in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, lint

I've added ***Flutter*** and ***Dart*** linting to my project. It works when I manually run `flutter analyze` in the terminal. But would like to add the `flutter analyze` as a build step to each time I run the app. Because I want a fast feedback loop when something is not correct before I push the code to our CI/CD pipeline.

How do I do that in Android Studio? I'm using the `flutter analyze` to run the Dart and Flutter linter

Comment: Can that be added to the Preferences | Tools | Actions on Save ??

Comment: It doesn't look you can add custom steps there.